# Is there a way to run my python test on selenium grid through my docker image?

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, dockerfile, pytest, selenium-grid

I am trying to run my python application which consists of test-cases by bundling them into a docker image. Then run them on a selenium grid on Chrome and Firefox nodes.

I am not able to run my application successfully, by building a docker image for my python app.

1- I've tried building my image, pushing it to my docker hub and retrieving it through a docker-compose file with all the services together (Selenium grid, nodes, app).

2 - I've tried building my image separately from the docker-compose file. After composing the (Selenium Grid and nodes) up; I manually build my docker image for the python app and use {docker run [image-name]} to run the application.

None of the above two methods worked for me.

Dockerfile for python app

```
FROM python: latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./myapp /app

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

CMD ["pytest","-n2","-s"]
```

Docker-compose file

Do I need a network ?? can I achieve what I want without the network I've created within this docker-compose file?

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59
    networks:
      q2cnw: {}
    environment:
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=50
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=60000
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=60000
      - GRID_NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT=60000
      - GRID_MAX_INSTANCES=3
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    depends_on:
      - hub
    networks:
      q2cnw: {}
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "9001:5900"
    links:
      - hub


  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    depends_on:
      - hub
    networks:
      q2cnw: {}
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "9002:5900"
    links:
      - hub

  app:
    container_name: demo_pytest_app
    image: {docker-image-from-repository}
    networks:
      q2cnw: {}
    ports:
      - "8080"

networks:
  q2cnw:
    driver: bridge
```

my conftest.py file

are there any changes for the URL, according to the docker-compose above?

```
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    )
```

Expected result:
(this shows it ran my browser and the application which threw an expected error; which I'm fine with)

```
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible']")
>           raise Exception("ERROR MESSAGE BANNER PROBLEM")
E           Exception: ERROR MESSAGE BANNER PROBLEM
```

Actual result:

(i used this command to run the pytest image -> [docker run -it pytest-image])

The below error indicates that connection is being refused due to host URL. Does anyone knows about this error that occurs when we are trying to connect our app to selenium grid + nodes through a docker image ??

```
E           urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnect
ionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f29f02f2a10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: I really hope someone could guide me through the right direction. i just need some hints. Thank you everyone....

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this image - https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/benjose22/selenium_pytest_remote

How to run -
 Step 1: Spin Docker-compose per https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#via-docker-compose
 Step 2: `docker run --network="host" -it -v ~/host_scripts:/src benjose22/selenium_pytest_remote:v1.0 test_sample.py`

`conftest.py` can be like -

```py
        caps = {'browserName': os.getenv('BROWSER', 'firefox')}<br/>
        self.browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=caps)
```